# Excel merging spread sheets

Tags: database, excel

I was wondering how to merge excel spread sheets. I have 2 spread sheets with a Ticker# column, I need to insert all the columns in sheet 2 to the corresponding Ticket# in sheet1. I can't just copy and paste them all because the ordering is different, and not all Ticket# exist in both sheets.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You will need to use VBA code to do this. If you do not know VBA, you should read tutorials and then ask us question. One method to help you is to use the macro recorder and then modify the code it produced to better match your need.

Comment: i'm familiar with VBA, although still inexperienced. Could you point me in the direction as to how I should go about doing this with VBA?

Comment: This does not have to be VBA, you can also use the MS Query method if you are farmiliar with SQL or Access. Are you?

Answer (score 0):

Use vlookup (or hlookup if you're using rows instead of columns) to find the information, if you need it saved in one sheet, you can copy that sheet and paste it into a new file and save as.

if you can share the file, I can give you the correct function. Or if you can give me a sample of data of both sheets.

Comment: vlookup will not merge, it will fill in the gaps on 1 spreadsheet from data gathered from the 2nd spreadsheet. If your data is going to continue to be generated in 2 spreadsheets, this is your permanent solution. If your data is going to switch to be kept in 1 spreadsheet, then this would get your data to 1. You can also use VBA as referenced above, but it'd take more effort than a vlookup, copy and paste and give you the same result

Comment: It depends on the needs for this application. Here at work we almost always need our tasks to be entirely automated because most users have  only functional knowledge of Excel. If you can assume your users to be experienced with Excel then this is easier though in long run the cost in time of coding the algorithm to achieve this tasks will pay itself. Also, using VLOOKUP() you will need to make sure that your temporary list contains all the elements to be matched against otherwise you will be missing some while in VBA you can just iterate through all elements and not miss any.

Comment: hey, I was able to create a quick fix using Vlookup, and it worked like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: Good to hear, if the answer worked for you, make sure you mark it as an answer to your question for future users